# how to get the updated value when saving in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

In my component I get some props from state like this:

```
computed: mapGetters({
      id: 'downloadId',
      pageLimit: 'pageLimit',
      pageMaxSize: 'pageMaxSize',
      cleaningInterval: 'cleaningInterval'
    })
```

and I bind the property:

```
<input type="number" v-model.number="pageLimit" id="pageMaxSize" />
```

Save method:

```
methods: {
  onSave () {
    alert('Your data: ' + JSON.stringify(this.pageLimit))
  }
}
```

When a value is entered into the input field and the save button is clicked, `this.pageLimit` remains the initial value

how do I get the updated value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two issues with your code:

1. `v-model` should be used with `data` only and not with `computed`. a `computed` property value in Vue.js can not be changed unless the value or one of the values it depends on has changed.
2. You can not update the state directly. This is one of vuex rules. To update it you have to use a vuex mutation for that.

So the solution is:

1. Create a `data` property called `tempPageLimit` and bind it to the input using `v-model`.
2. In the `store`, Create a mutation that update the `pageLimit` with the value of the `tempPageLimit` and map it to your component using `mapMutations`.
3. Execute this mutation inside the `onSave` method.

look [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) if you want to read about vuex mutations.

Comment: `v-model` can be used with computed values, you just need to provide a setter. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter